# Sockets Through proxy in python

Tags: python

Hello
Is there any way to connect through a proxy using sockets in python.
This is giving me an error

```
import socket, sys
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("www.python.org", 80))

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
soc.connect(("http://www.python.org",80))
File "<string>", line 1, in connect
gaierror: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [SocksiPy](http://socksipy.sourceforge.net/): it'll establish a connection to your proxy server and do all that work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue using `urllib2` like so:

```
import urllib2 

opener = urllib2.build_opener(
     urllib2.ProxyHandler({"http":"proxy_ip_address:port_number";}),
     urllib2.ProxyHandler({"https":"proxy_ip_address:port_number";}),
)
urllib2.install_opener(opener) 

for line in urllib2.urlopen("py4inf.com/code/romeo.txt"): 
    print line.strip()
```