# How to get my IP with Python 3, socket and proxy (TOR)?

Tags: python, sockets, proxy, tor

I've tried to use some third-party services like [ipify.com](https://www.ipify.org/), but it's pretty easy to get `Max retries` exception, because I'm sending a lot of requests.

So I've found a really simple way to get my IP through Google DNS ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/166589/6843935)). Here's the code:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.connect(("8.8.8.8", 80))
print(s.getsockname()[0])
s.close()
```

Also, I've read a few articles ([link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993017/sockets-through-proxy-in-python), [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32792333/python-socket-module-connecting-to-an-http-proxy-then-performing-a-get-request), [link 3](https://gist.github.com/frxstrem/4487802)) and in my understanding, it's pretty easy to send `HTTP GET` request via proxy with `socket` module.

But I can't understand, how can I merge this two techniques and connect to 8.8.8.8 via proxy.

Need your help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot merge those techniques because you're using DGRAM (UDP) sockets, [and Tor only proxies TCP connections](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#TransportIPnotTCP).

So you need to connect to a TCP-based server. The best choice would be your own server - it is fairly easy to set up something on AWS dumping SERVER_IP, and depending on your load it probably won't cost much - if anything. Or you can use free IP query servers, but rotate them (using different server in each request), to ensure you won't exceed the allowed threshold.